# Specify swift interpreter version in swift script

Tags: swift, scripting

I'd assume this would mean to run the script with whatever swift is installed on the system: `#!/usr/bin/swift`

How do I specify interpreter version the script is intended for?

Answer (score 0):

[Cato](https://github.com/neonichu/cato) can be used for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cato 1.2
```

Comment: While this would probably work, anyone user who pulls my script from github would need to install cato; I'd prefer solution without 3rd parties.